# Danu is the predecessor of the race of Danavas (demons)

Tags: puranas, asuras

In Brahmanda Purana,
http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/brahmananda_purana/preaching_of_bruhaspati.html

> Bruhaspati replied "In the distant past, Diti, the second wife of Kashyapa gave birth to a son by name Danu and a daughter named Rupavati. Danu is the predecessor of the race of Danavas (demons). Rupavati was married to Brahma (the Creator).

I am confused about this, Is Danu the first demon? and before him there is no demons?

please I need an answer to finish my research.

Comment: Diti, the second wife of Kashyapa gave birth to a son by name Danu and a daughter named Rupavati. Danu is the predecessor of the race of Danavas (demons).

Comment: diti was the wife and gave birth boy and girl, the boy's name was danu. this is what I understood. plz explain what I  missed.

Comment: Danvas are not only Demons...the list includes Daityas, Rakshasas and others as well...Madhu, Kaitabh (born from Lord Vishnu's ears) seems ancient demons... Hiranyakashipu, Hirnaksh from Daityas; Viprachiti and brothers from Danvas; Heti, Praheti from Rakshasas are also ancient...and..as per most of other Puranas, Danu is wife of Kashyap along with Aditi, Diti and others ..Aditi's sons Adityas; Diti's sons Daityas; Danu's sons Danvas...

Comment: I don't know the significance of the text in question but as per major puranas, Sage Kashyap has more wives too than Diti and Aditi, so one of the wife was Danu, and it was her sons and their successors who came to be known as Danav. So, Danav is just a clan that came out of Danu. And also, Danav doesn't mean demon. Its because of the activities of Danu clan that we compare them today with demons.

Comment: Clan names are commonly seen in Hindu mythology, like Manu's successors are known as Manav, Kuru's Successors are known as Kaurav, Pandu 's successors are known as Pandav so similarly Danu's successors are known as Danav

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Danu was the mother of Danavas.

In Rig Veda [I.32.9](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01032.htm) Danu was mentioned as the mother of Vritra, whom Indra killed.

> Then humbled was the strength of Vṛtra's mother: Indra hath cast his
>   deadly bolt against her. The mother was above, the son was under and
>   like a cow beside her calf lay ***Danu***.