# Is Maya Dānava the first Dānava?

Tags: indra, asuras, ancestry

Maya is mentioned so often and without Dānava parents, it points to him being the first of the Dānava. Has anyone found scripture to say definitively?

Comment: But, wikipedia says that Ramayana mentions Kashyap and Diti as Mayasura's parents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Danu is the predecessor of the race of Danavas (demons)](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27256/danu-is-the-predecessor-of-the-race-of-danavas-demons)

Comment: Never heard about Maya Danava before? Which texts talk about it?

Comment: The Dānava race came from Diti/Danu, but that does not mean Diti/Danu is a Dānava, as she could also be the same race as her father Daksha, who is definitely not a Dānava. The first Dānava would then be the first of her children so to transform into the then new Dānava race.

Comment: Maya Dānava appears nearly everywhere in Hinduism. He is important at critical moments in the Mahābhārata and Rāmāyaṇa and is built Tripura, the famous flying cities.

Answer (score 2):

No, Maya Dānava is not the first Dānava. His was son of Danu (but not the eldest). ~ [Is Mayasura a Daitya or Danava? What is the important difference between these two groups?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/50260/is-mayasura-a-daitya-or-danava-what-is-the-important-difference-between-these-t/50262#50262)

**Dānavas are descendant of Danu** and Kashyapa.

The **first Dānava** (eldest and first king of Danavas i.e. sons of Danu) was **Vipracitti**:

- > The highly effulgent Hiranyakashipu was appointed the king of Daityas and Hiranyaksha as the heir apparent. **The highly powerful and first born Vipracitti was appointed the king of Danavas** and Asuras. ~ [Harivamsha Purana: Part 3: Chapter 33 - Various Kings are Appointed by Brahma](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/harivamsha-purana-dutt/d/doc485706.html)
- > And Danu had forty sons, O Bharata! The **eldest of them all was Viprachitti** of great fame... ~[Mahabharata: Adi Parva: Sambhava Parva: Chapter 65](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01066.htm)
- > The sons of Danu were great Asuras well known in their race. The most important among them was Vipracitti. ~ [The Brahmanda Purana:  Section 3 - Upodghāta-pāda: Chapter 6 - Glorification of The Race of Danu](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahmanda-purana/d/doc362863.html)
- > From Kaśyapa, Danu obtained a hundred sons proud of boons. Among them Vipracitti, of great power, was the chief. ~ [Padma Purana: Section 1 - Sṛṣṭi-khaṇḍa: Chapter 6 - Birth of Devas, Daityas, Birds and Serpents etc.](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc364126.html)